# androiod: Arraylist getview with ImageView returns only the last data

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, imageview, placeholder

```
ArrayList<Message> msg;
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Message message = (Message) this.getItem(position);
    Holder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new Holder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.activity_list, parent, false);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    mAlphaSplit = new Character[message.getMessage().length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < message.getMessage().length(); i++) {
        mAlphaSplit[i] = new Character(message.getMessage().charAt(i));
        for (int j = 0; j < ALPHA.length; j++) {
            if (mAlphaSplit[i] == ALPHA[j]) {
                holder.imageView.setImageResource(ICONS[j]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) holder.imageView.getLayoutParams();
    if (message.isMine()) {
        holder.imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_mine);
        lp.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
    } else {
        holder.imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_not_mine);
        lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
    }
    holder.imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
    return convertView;
}
```

this is my getview method. I would like to get the corresponding images of each letter but after I inputted something. the last corresponding image will only be the one to be returned.

my getCount

```
public int getCount() {
    return msg.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in your loop.

```
    mAlphaSplit = new Character[message.getMessage().length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < message.getMessage().length(); i++) {
        mAlphaSplit[i] = new Character(message.getMessage().charAt(i));
        for (int j = 0; j < ALPHA.length; j++) {
            if (mAlphaSplit[i] == ALPHA[j]) {
                holder.imageView.setImageResource(ICONS[j]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now for each view you are searching all characters in mAlphaSplit with Alpha. It matches with every character, but everytime it gets a match, it set imageview. So if you have ['A','B','C'] in mAlphaSplit, then at first it matches with 'A', found it, then set image, then again find match for 'B' and then 'C'. So the image for C is set as it sets the image at last. I think do not need outer loop, rather use position like following.

```
        char mAlpha = message.getMessage().charAt(position);
        for (int j = 0; j < ALPHA.length; j++) {
            if (mAlpha == ALPHA[j]) {
                holder.imageView.setImageResource(ICONS[j]);
                break;
            }
        }
```

And your getCount

```
public int getCount() {
    if(message==null||message.getMessage()==null) return 0;
    return message.getMessage().size();
}
```

Comment: I already tried that line of code but when I try to run the project. It has NullPointerException at the line `if (mAlphaSplit[position] == ALPHA[j])`

Comment: it says "StringIndexOutOfBoundsException" at the line `if (mAlpha == ALPHA[j])`

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-20 11:53:58.348 29163-29163/com.app.messaging.messagingapp E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.app.messaging.messagingapp, PID: 29163
10-20 11:53:58.348 29163-29163/com.app.messaging.messagingapp E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=10

Comment: can you post the getCount functions body.

Comment: I think your getCount returning more than length of getMessage() string length.

Comment: In your getcount it should be, return message.getMessage().length().

Comment: but it says a NPE on the getCount method

Comment: I have edited code again, Now i think initially your message is empty or null, if value change after some time, you should call notifyDataSetChange()